# I want to convert an array represeantation of left balanced binary tree from In-order to Level order representation:

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, implementation

As shown in the following fig, I have a program which stores data of a tree in in-order manner.

[image]

for example: `A[7]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6};`

I want that to convert in level-order manner: Such that the first node is root, and left children can be found at 2i+1 the location, right child can be found at 2i+2 th location, and parent of any node can be found at i/2th location.

Namely:

```
B[0]=A[3]
B[1]=A[1]
B[2]=A[5]
B[3]=A[0]
B[4]=A[2]
B[5]=A[4] and
B[6]=A[6]
```

I am stuck and unable to find any strategy.

I need to perform this operation to make a compatible tree structure for an algorithm I've written earlier.

The data set contains thousand of nodes and it's impossible to do it manually. Kindly suggest a iterative or recursive algorithm for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not much confidence...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void toOrder(int a[], int b[], size_t index, size_t size, size_t a_size){
    int i;

    if(index >= a_size) return;
    if(size == 1){
        b[index] = a[0];
        return;
    }
    size /=2;
    b[index]=a[size];
    toOrder(&a[0]     , b, index * 2 + 1, size, a_size);
    toOrder(&a[size+1], b, index * 2 + 2, size, a_size);
}


#define SIZE 7

int main(void){
    int a[SIZE] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int b[SIZE];
    int i;

    toOrder(a, b, 0, SIZE, SIZE);
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
        printf("b[%d]=%d\n", i, b[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This code works perfectly.I have tried different instances of Left Balanced Binary trees, it's giving perfect result. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm that takes one record-keeping sweep and then one output.

Take an array of the size of the tree, n.

Create a record-keeping array **depths** of size depth, initialized to 0. Each entry is how many nodes are at depth i.

Walk the tree, noting each node's depth. At each node:

```
depths[d] += 1
```

This'll leave you with a list of how many nodes are at each depth.

Make a new array, **depth-offset**. Where **depth-offset[i]** = **depth-offset[i-1]** + **depths[i-1]** and **depth-offset[0]** = 0. This shows you where a node of a given depth starts in the output array. Now it's just a matter of walking and placing, while incrementing the position of the next node at that level.

Walk the tree in-order, noting the depth again.

```
offset = depth-offset[d]
output[offset] = value-at-node
depth-offset[d] = depth-offset[d]+1
```

output should be your list.